# interating through a list of lists to create a new list

Tags: python, list

i've been trying to strengthen my skills in lists, especially lists of lists.  I have a list of people right now that I set up in a list of lists.  A snippet of it is shown below.  I set it up so the the list consists of [name, parent, parent].

```
group = [[steve,adam,avery],[avery, sarah, henry], [adam, harry, jane], [john, helene, bill], [andrew, helene, bill], [david, bill, helene]]
```

I want to iterate through the list of lists in order to create a new lists of lists that displays [name, parent, parent, grandparent, grandparent].   if there is no grandparent to show, then a 0 should show.

Sample output:

```
[[steve, adam, avery, sarah, henry, harry, jane], [avery, sarah, henry, 0, 0, 0, 0], [adam, harry, jane, 0, 0, 0, 0], [john, helene bill, 0, 0, 0, 0], [andrew, helene, bill, 0,0, 0, 0], [david, bill, helene, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I tried interating with a for loop in range(0, len(group)) but kept receiving an error.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are `harry, jane` not in the first sublist?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: "a 0 should show"... for your information in Python you usually use `None` to indicate a missing value. Also "Do you have a grandparent? None" makes sense while "Do you have a grand parent? 0" doesn't, so it's even closer to natural language.

Comment: very sorry, put the desired output there too fast, i want both grandparents.  fixed it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to build a mapping of name to parents first:

```
parents = {n: [p1, p2] for n, p1, p2 in group}
```

Now you can look up parents to build a new list:

```
[[n, p1, p2] + parents.get(p1, [0, 0]) + parents.get(p2, [0, 0])
 for n, p1, p2 in group]
```

Demo:

```
>>> group = [['steve', 'adam', 'avery'], ['avery', 'sarah', 'henry'], ['adam', 'harry', 'jane'], ['john', 'helene', 'bill'], ['andrew', 'helene', 'bill'], ['david', 'bill', 'helene']]
>>> parents = {n: [p1, p2] for n, p1, p2 in group}
>>> [[n, p1, p2] + parents.get(p1, [0, 0]) + parents.get(p2, [0, 0])
...  for n, p1, p2 in group]
[['steve', 'adam', 'avery', 'harry', 'jane', 'sarah', 'henry'], ['avery', 'sarah', 'henry', 0, 0, 0, 0], ['adam', 'harry', 'jane', 0, 0, 0, 0], ['john', 'helene', 'bill', 0, 0, 0, 0], ['andrew', 'helene', 'bill', 0, 0, 0, 0], ['david', 'bill', 'helene', 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: wow awesome- thanks!  it seems it may make my life easier to use dictionaries - did not realize that myself!

Comment: awesome - just did - learned a lot.  haha now i'm more interested in how to do this iteration with dictionaries.  just tried for an hour with no avail.

parents = {n: [p1, p2] for n, p1, p2 in group}

this creates the dic.  if i want to append to the list in the dic, not include the 0s this time, just grandparents if they are there, so some lists will be shorter than others.  my prob is if someone doesn't have a grandparent i get an error - yikes.

Comment: @WycG: Have `dict.get()` return an empty list in that case: `[n, p1, p2] + parents.get(p1, []) + parents.get(p2, [])`. That'll concatenate empty lists instead of `[0, 0]` if the name is not present in the `parents` dictionary.